# non-parametric supervised learning method

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

In the documentation of [Scikit-Learn Decision Trees](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html), it is stated that:

> Decision Trees (DTs) are a non-parametric supervised learning method used for classification and regression. The goal is to create a model that predicts the value of a target variable by learning simple decision rules inferred from the data features.

What is meant by *non-parametric supervised learning*?

Comment: Maybe this answers your question [parametric vs non-parametric models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/268638/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-a-parametric-and-non-parametric-model)

Answer (score 1):

`non-parametric` is on the opposite side of `parametric`. In a parametric learning model, you can describe the set of the hypothesis (or learning model) as a function of a finite number of parameters such as SVM.
Hence, a non-parametric model can be seen as a model with an infinite number of parameters to be described, i.e., the distribution of data cannot be defined by a finite set of parameters [[1]](http://mlss.tuebingen.mpg.de/2015/slides/ghahramani/gp-neural-nets15.pdf).

> [[2]](https://machinelearningmastery.com/parametric-and-nonparametric-machine-learning-algorithms/) An easy to understand nonparametric model is the k-nearest neighbors algorithm that makes predictions based on the k most similar training patterns for a new data instance. The method does not assume anything about the form of the mapping function other than patterns that are close are likely to have a similar output variable.